# Sub Query Vlookup

Tags: sql, excel, vlookup, with-statement

Edited: 11/23/2016 10:32

Ok so I am new to SQL and have gotten pretty good at the basics but need some help on moving this analysis from Excel to query based. I think this rquires a WITH statement and I only have permission with our data to view/select statements. So my query would need to be a session based view.

I have two queries [Install query] and [Service query] that i import into excel.
InstallQuery  1: Excel Sheet 1
Service Query 2: Excel Sheet 2

the two queries are the same exept they have differnt where conditions

[Install Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffyMz.jpg)

[Service table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYA7r.jpg)

the link between the two excel sheets is (site number) think of this as a numerical address equivalent.

I want to calculate how many of our Install Jobs have a service call in 60 days. So in excel I do this by first taking the Install query sheet 1 and insert a new calculated column "Warrant Date" which takes and existing date column "Onsite Date" and adds 60 days. Which is as follows: 
Onsite Date + 60 days= Warranty date.

Then i vlookup the site number from the install query sheet 1 on the Service query sheet 2, if it finds a match I compare the service date to the install date. Using the logic  below in a new column called "Warranty coverage"
      If Service Date<= Warranty Date 
            then "Covered" 
            else "Not Covered"

Currently results are in the install table sheet with in excel with all the columns from the Install table with the addition of Warranty Coverage column

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the use of a case statement - to give you a derived column based on the relevant criteria.
Join the tables on the relevant column, then select the results you want - (I've aliased the tables for clarity) in this example:

```
  SELECT ST.*
            ,CASE 
                WHEN [Service Date] <= [Warranty Date]
                    THEN 'Covered'
                ELSE 'Not Covered'
                END as 'Warranty coverage'
        FROM [Install table] AS IT
        INNER JOIN [Service table] AS ST
            ON IT.[site number] = ST.[site number]
```

Comment: I miss spoke my tables are excel sheets that i populate through two queries that are basically the same that just have different "Where" conditions but every thing else is the same including the "From" statement